# How do I declare new oxml/xmlchemy tags in python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to build basic equation functionality into python-docx to output formulas to docx files. Can someone go over the standard-operating procedure for registering a new class in oxml? Looking at the source code, a tag appears to be declared by creating a complex-type class

```
class CT_P(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    ''<w:p>'' element, containing the properties and text for a paragraph.
    """
    pPr = ZeroOrOne('w:pPr')
    r = ZeroOrMore('w:r')
```

and then registering it using the register_element_cls() function

```
from .text.paragraph import CT_P
register_element_cls('w:p', CT_P)
```

Some classes include other methods, but many do not, so it looks like a minimum working example would be this:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import BaseOxmlElement, ZeroOrOne, ZeroOrMore, OxmlElement
import docx.oxml
docx.oxml.ns.nsmap['m'] = ('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math')

class CT_OMathPara(BaseOxmlElement):
    r = ZeroOrMore('w:r')

docx.oxml.register_element_cls('m:oMathPara',CT_OMathPara)  
p = CT_OMathPara()
```

(Note that I have to declare the m namespace, since it is not used in the package). Unfortunately this doesn't work for me at all. If I declare a new class derived as in the above example, and then check, for instance, the `__repr__` of this new class, it causes an exception

```
>> p

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\ns.py", line 50, in from_clark_name
    nsuri, local_name = clark_name[1:].split('}')

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This happens because the tag in my class is very different from a w:p tag created from the python-docx package

```
>> paragraph._element.tag
 '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}p'

>> p.tag
 'CT_OMathPara'
```

But I don't know why this is. A file search through the source code does not reveal any other mentions of the CT_P class, so I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is coming from the 'm' namespace prefix (nspfx) not being present in the `docx.oxml.ns.pfxmap` dict. The namespace needs to be looked up both ways (from nspfx to namespace url *and* from url to nspfx).

So to add the new namespace from "outside", meaning after the `ns` module is loaded, you'll need to do both (if you were to patch the `ns` module code directly, that second step would be handled automatically at load time):

```
nsmap, pfxmap = docx.oxml.ns.nsmap, docx.oxml.ns.pfxmap
nsmap['m'] = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math'
pfxmap['http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math'] = 'm'
```

This should get you to past the error you're getting, however there's a little more to understand.

The `CT_OMathPara` class is an example of what's known as a *custom element class*. This means that `lxml` instantiates an object of this class for each element with the registered tag (`m:oMathPara`) instead of the generic `lxml` `_Element` class.

The key thing is, *you need to let `lxml` do the constructing*, which happens when it parses the XML. You can't get a meaningful object by constructing that class yourself.

The easiest way to create a new "loose" element (not lodged in an XML document tree) is to use `docx.oxml.OxmlElement()`:

```
oMathPara = OxmlElement('m:oMathPara')
```

More commonly though, the `docx.oxml.parse_xml()` function is used to parse an entire XML snippet. A parser needs to be configured to use custom element classes and those elements have to be registered with the parser, so you probably don't want to do that for yourself when the one in the `oxml` module will take care of all the needful.

So usually, to get an instance of `CT_OMathPara`, you would just open a docx that contained a `m:oMathPara` element (after registering the new namespace and custom element class), but you can also just parse in an XML snippet. If you search for `parse_xml` in the `oxml` modules you'll find plenty of examples. You need to get the namespace declarations right at the top of the XML you provide, which can be a little tricky, but you can certainly just spell out the entire XML snippet in text if you want, it just gets a bit verbose.

Comment: The suggested call to the constructor for OxmlElement('m:oMathPara') works. For whatever reason, calling parse_xml does not. It generates an XMLSyntaxError (saying prefix m is undefined), even when I add the entry to ns.py. Is there another place it must be added also?

Comment: All valid XML must declare all the namespaces it uses. So the root element needs to have an “attribute” like xmlns:m=“http:...”